# "Ctrl + C" buttons pressed handle C# console app

Tags: c#, event-handling, console-application

How can I handle two buttons pressed simultaneously ('Ctrl' + 'C'),  not in the WindowsForms application, but in console C# application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you want to set [`Console.TreatCtrlCAsInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.treatcontrolcasinput.aspx) to `true`. (Assuming you *don't* want this to terminate the app.)

Comment: actually I want to add a log and only than terminate the app. thank you, will try ur advice

Answer (score 3):

Check out **[Console.TreatControlCAsInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.treatcontrolcasinput.aspx)** property;

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the combination of the Control
>   modifier key and C console key (Ctrl+C) is treated as ordinary input
>   or as an interruption that is handled by the operating system.